# Git stash pop - lost untracked files

Tags: git, git-stash, git-untracked

after "git pull" I got the message that my local changes would be overwritten for some files so that I have to commit my changes or stash them before merge.

Unfortunately I did "git stash" and afterwards "git stash pop".

That repo is just for my notes, so there is only a master I'm wokring on.
The git version is: 2.16.1.windows.4

Then I used "git stash apply" and "git stash apply 2" and "git stash apply 0".
The question I have is: Is there a chance to get my untracked files back by doing git commands?

I already saw that I had to use the parameter -u, but the fault was done, so I only want to know if there is a way.

Comment: Normally, Git does not overwrite untracked files (except when they are mentioned in `.gitignore`). It is unclear at which point they would have been overwritten or removed.

Comment: Also, when you say *afterwards "git stash pop"*, after what did you do that? After the pull?